# Issue trying to check for symbol an string

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm having an issue trying to find a symbol in a string. What I'm trying to do is to check the symbol - exists in place of space in a channel name.

The channel name is the username of user. However usernames can have spaces and Discord denotes channel name spaces as "-" for example if a username is "Joe Blogs" the channel name would be "#Joe-Blogs".

Here is what I'm working with:

```
chars = set('0123456789$,-')
 if channel.name and any((c in chars) for c in channel.name) == f"{user.name.lower()}{user.discriminator}":
                await ctx.send(f"Thread channel {channel.mention} already exists.")
                return
```

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this  for checking the username for foreign signs

```
import re
illegalcharacter = re.compile('[!@#$%^&*()-+={}|\":;<>,?/]')
search = illegalcharacter.search(username)
if search != None:
    #username has foreign signs
```

next for space i guess u could do

```
username = username.replace(' ', '-')
```